# Need to identify windshield washer fluid reservoir

Tags: part-identification, windshield-wipers

In January of 1992 I pulled a windshield washer fluid reservoir from a u-pull-it salvage yard in Illinois for a car that didn't have a factory washer unit.  I deliberately chose a unit with built-in pumps that was easy to remove, but I didn't write down the year/make/model of the donor vehicle and the receipt just says "washer bottle, $15".

The grommets for the pumps are now rotted and upon inspection the plastic reservoir also has a crack in it.

I've identified the pumps as part number 060210-1480 and although the pumps themselves work I can get the pump and grommet from several sources on eBay or Amazon for about $8 each.

However, given the crack in the bottle I'd like to see about replacing the whole unit.  I was hoping to work backward from the pump part number but it was used in dozens of models and googling by model I haven't seen images of one that looks like mine.

My fuzzy memories of that trip suggest it was pulled from something Japanese, possibly a Toyota.  It was definitely a van or wagon body as it has the dual pumps.

From my searching on Google it looks a lot like something from a 91-97 Suzuki Sidekick except taller.  Keeping in mind the date of the junkyard visit, it would have to be MY 1992 or older and something available in the Midwest US.

Can anyone point to a make, model, and year range for this part?

[image: Top View]
[image: Front View]
[image: Back View]

Answer (score 1):

The pumps which are on it bear the **nippondenso pn: 060210-1480** ... looking at one source there is a huge long listing of different vehicles which this would fit. Considering there are two pumps on it, I'd suggest it is setup for both a front and back washer. With that in mind, the pared down list I'm showing this could have come out of is as follows (I've also excluded newer than 92 entries):

```
 Chevrolet Tracker 1989-2004 (Front & Rear)
 Dodge Colt 1978-1992 (Front & Rear)
 Dodge Conquest 1984 (Fornt & Rear)
 Dodge Raider 1989 (Front & Rear)
 Ford Escort 1992-1996 (Front & Rear)
 Geo Metro 1989-1993 (Front & Rear)
 Plymouth Champ 1979-1982 (Front & Rear)
 Plymouth Colt 1979-1992 (Front & Rear)
 Suzuki Sidekick 1989-1998 (Front & Rear)
 Suzuki Swift 1989-1994 (Front & Rear)
```

I know this doesn't get you exactly the vehicle, but would suggest it might help remind you of the vehicle which you did get it out of.

**EDIT:**

I think you could actually pretty much eliminate the Escort as well, considering you probably wouldn't have found a brand new car in the U-Pull-It yard. Also, I'm pretty sure the Tracker and Sidekick were the same vehicle. Suzuki made the Tracker for Chevy. Considering these are Japanese (right), these might not have any markings on the parts, even though GM likes to mark their stuff up (as does Dodge and Ford as well).

Comment: Yeah, sadly there are no numbers stamped on the reservoir.  Agreed on the front and back also.

Comment: I did a Google Image Search on all of those, btw, and only the Suzuki bottle looked remotely close.  Of course, it could be my particular part isn't showing on GIS because it's a less-popular variant rather than it being a non-match.